# C/C++ with objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, xcode5

I want to put `C/C++` code into `Objective C` programs.
What's the exact way to do that ?
I've tried many times.

So, if someone know how to that, please explain the way from zero (from a empty project) and give me some class examples ;)
(i work on Xcode 5.0.2)
Thank you !

Comment: Read about [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B), and do some searching.

Comment: you can dump C into your objective-C straight off the bat, if you want to use c++, rename your .m files to .mm which makes them objective-c++

Answer (score 2):

Using XCode, rename the file extension of the files with C++ code from .m to .mm for C++. 
Objective C is a superset of C, so pure C code will compile without any required changes.

Comment: I created a OBJ-C class with header (.m and .h) and renamed it to .mm, i put something of c++ in the .mm, i got nothing, i tried to #import <stdlib> -> Red error -> Not found.

Can someone gave me an example of code ? And how to instatiate it if there's a special way ?

Comment: help please, i need help

Comment: Have you tried #include <stdlib.h> ? If that still doesn't work, I suggest opening a new question, giving an example of the code you're using and describe the problem, as this is now different from the original question you posed here.